# How would you write this code in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I'm trying to learn assembly on my own, but I'm confused on how to write a recursive function that calls itself more than once in the return statement.

This is the function in C:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = rec3(5);
    printf("%d", a);

  return 0;
}

int recursion(int x) {
    if (x > 0) {
    return x  + recursion(x-1) + recursion(x-2);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is what I've gotten upto so far:

```
.text
main: 

    li $v0, 5 #Read in an int
    syscall

    move $a0, $v0 #Move the int to argument
    jal Rec #Call Recursion function

    move $a0, $v0 #Print the value 
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall


Rec:    subu $sp, $sp, 8
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)




Done:   lw $ra, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, ($sp)
    addu $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra
```

I haven't written the recursive part of the function because I'm so lost on how to do it. Can anyone write out the recursive part so I have an understanding of how to solve it? I also want to clarify, this isn't a school project or anything like that. I am just trying to understand how to do recursion in MIPS Assembly so I made my own function.

Comment: *Can someone finish this code for me?* isn't an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can transform it into this, right?

```
   int tmp1 = recursion(x-1);
   int tmp2 = recursion(x-2);
   return x  + tmp1 + tmp2;
```

If it was literally having multiple recursive calls "in the return statement" that was confusing for you, does that help?

The first temporary you invent has to be saved somewhere (e.g. a call-preserved register) across the 2nd function call as part of evaluating that expression.  Just like any time you need some data to survive across a function call.

The way a compiler would do it is to save/restore a couple call-preserved registers like `$s0` and `$s1` at the start/end of the function, and use them within the function for `x` and that temporary.

Or optimize that and only save `x + recursion(x-1)` in a single register, so you only need that and the return value after the 2nd function call returns.

---

Of course an *optimizing* compiler would turn some of this recursion into a loop, and not actually generate assembly that recursed as much.  By hand you could even simplify it down to a modified Fibonacci loop with O(n) runtime instead of O(Fib(n)), just keeping the last two sequence values in registers.  That's how to implement this function efficiently, but wouldn't teach you about recursion.  Unfortunately this function is an example of a case where recursion is inconvenient and the worst way to implement this calculation.

(I mostly mention this because you asked how *I* would write this code in asm.  I'd write asm that had the same observable results as the C, applying the as-if rule like the C standard allows compilers to do.  Being recursive doesn't count as an observable result in ISO C.  Obviously that's not what you should actually do for an assignment or to learn about recursion.)